# Orientation of body

Tags: accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope, magnetometer, tilt

We need to find the patient monitoring system which monitors the position of the body of the patient when patient is on bed . what we want to get is when patient is sleeping we want to monitor what is the position in which he/she is whether he is sleeping facing celing , or sleeping facing left side,or sleeping facing right side .
What we are using is IMU SENSOR and we have the gyro , accelerometer, magnetometer reading in xyz planes . please suggest what to do further in order to find above positions.

Answer (score 0):

With only one (simple) sensor attached to a body, it's rather difficult. With *multiple* sensors (and the ability to distinguish between them), you could possibly triangulate each of them to get relative distances on the three spatial axes.

But, without more information than you currently have (including perhaps some details on *what* the sensor actually senses), I don't think it's possible.